# Python/XML: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable

Tags: python, xml, lxml

I have list of elements that I need to apply and store into a variable. For some reason it not accepting elements from list?

```
import glob
import xmltodict
import lxml.etree as etree

xml_files = glob.glob('dir/*.xml')

list_of_xml = []
for l in [etree.parse(x) for x in xml_files]:
    list_of_xml.append(l)
print(list_of_xml)

# printOutput
[<lxml.etree._ElementTree at 0x17406866b88>,
 <lxml.etree._ElementTree at 0x17406795cc8>,
 <lxml.etree._ElementTree at 0x174068ed7c8>]

for e in list_of_xml():
    store_into_a_variable = xmltodict.parse(etree.tostring(e))


# error: TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Why am I getting this error? I have used this for loop kind of function/notation many times to get a certain output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't call a list like a function so:

`for e in list_of_xml():` should be `for e in list_of_xml:`

Your entire snippet should be:

```
import glob
import xmltodict
import lxml.etree as etree

xml_files = glob.glob('dir/*.xml')

list_of_xml = []
for l in [etree.parse(x) for x in xml_files]:
    list_of_xml.append(l)
print(list_of_xml)

# printOutput
[<lxml.etree._ElementTree at 0x17406866b88>,
 <lxml.etree._ElementTree at 0x17406795cc8>,
 <lxml.etree._ElementTree at 0x174068ed7c8>]

for e in list_of_xml:
    store_into_a_variable = xmltodict.parse(etree.tostring(e))
```